# I have an issue with the redirection from the external URL back to my app

Tags: php, cordova, redirect, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

Situation: I want a user to visit external URL, which offers the authentication service. When a user access to the external page throughout the inappbrowser, there is no problem with the authentication process. However, when its user finishes the authentication process, the page redirection to my app is not working. 
To be more accurate, I will explain about the intended workflow here:
users click a authentication button -> my app opens a webview that shows the external page which provides the authentication service by using the inappbrowser plugin -> users fill out a form and proceed to complete the authentication -> user click the confirm or complete button -> authenticated user info goes into the receiving php, which is along with the path of my app's domain -> from the php page, which the authentication info is landed, the page is redirected to our app.

However, there is a problem with the end of the above process. When I try to redirect the webview page back to my app, it is not working and just stuck in the php page, even though I put the page redirection codes in the page, such as window.location.href or location.href

Ionic version & plugins version used: 
ionic 1.3.1
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.4.0

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: If it's your PHP handling it, check your error logs - might be a `"Headers already sent...."` issue

Comment: thank you for your comment. I will check it out!